# How to do highlighting within HibernateSearch over Elasticsearch

Tags: java, hibernate, elasticsearch, hibernate-search

Background: We're in the process of converting our java application from Lucene to Elasticsearch 5.6.6.  Using Hibernate 5.2.11 and Hibernate-Search 5.8.2.  We have a number of custom Analyzers which get registered with ES (using ElasticsearchAnalysisDefinitionProvider per the [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#_custom_analyzers_using_a_definition_provider)) and have imported them as a plugin into the ES server.

For basic querying, using the Query DSL seems fairly straightforward, however there's a highlighting chunk of code that that I've been unable to get working.

Analyzers in ES are a bit more removed than when dealing with Lucene directly and that might be one of my main problems.

Here's the existing method we need to get converted/working; currently getting a NullPointerException within the 3rd line down that calls: `...getAnalyzer(analyzerName)`, I tracked it to ImmutableSearchFactory::getAnalyzer when it does `SearchIntegration integration = integrations.get( LuceneEmbeddedIndexManagerType.INSTANCE )`

```
private boolean isMatch(String field, String target, String analyzerName, Query sourceQ, FullTextSession fts) {

    Analyzer analyzer = fts.getSearchFactory().getAnalyzer(analyzerName);

    Highlighter highlighter = new Highlighter(new QueryScorer(sourceQ, field));
    highlighter.setTextFragmenter(new NullFragmenter());

    try {
        String result = highlighter.getBestFragment(analyzer, field, target);
        return StringUtils.hasText(result);
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Caught IOException while highlighting a String?..", e);
    }
    catch (InvalidTokenOffsetsException e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Caught InvalidTokenOffsetsException while highlighting a String?..", e);
    }
}
```

Is there another way to get the analyzer or something incorrect here?
But more importantly, how do you highlight a fragment when using Hibernate Search over ES?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there another way to get the analyzer or something incorrect here?

You cannot get the an instance of `org.apache.lucene.analysis.Analyzer` if you defined your analyzer for Elasticsearch, because in that case the analyzer only lives on the remote Elasticsearch cluster, and Hibernate Search never uses the analyzer directly: it only pushes the analyzer definition to Elasticsearch and then uses references to that analyzer (the name).

What you are trying to do is to use an analyzer that only exists in another server (the ES server) to run an analysis locally using Lucene. This cannot work.

> But more importantly, how do you highlight a fragment when using Hibernate Search over ES?

Hibernate Search itself does not provide highlighting capabilities; only Lucene, the technology that runs traditionally behind Hibernate Search, does. When you use the Elasticsearch integration, you are swapping the Lucene technology for the Elasticsearch technology (more or less). Thus you have to do things differently.

### Hibernate Search 6.x

Hibernate Search 6.0.0.Beta3+ offers a new API that allows you to take advantage of advanced Elasticsearch features more easily. If you want to highlight as part of a search query, there's no need to rely directly on the REST client anymore.

You can use a [request transformer](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/6.0/reference/en-US/html_single/#search-dsl-query-elasticsearch-json) to add a [`highlight` element](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.5/search-request-body.html#request-body-search-highlighting) to the HTTP request, then use the [`jsonHit` projection](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/6.0/reference/en-US/html_single/#search-dsl-projection-extensions-elasticsearch-jsonHit) to retrieve the JSON for each hit, which contains a `highlight` element that includes the highlighted fields and the highlighted fragments.

### Hibernate Search 5.x

In Hibernate Search 5.x, you do not have access to the raw JSON of the search request and response, so another approach is necessary.

One option would be for you to continue using Lucene. In order to do that, you will have to define the exact same analyzer, but for Lucene. You can use an [analysis definition provider](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/5.10/reference/en-US/html_single/#section-programmatic-analyzer-definition) pretty much the same way as with Elasticsearch.
Then you should be able to call `getAnalyzer()` to retrieve the Lucene analyzer and perform highlighting using Lucene APIs.

**There's one caveat, though**: if you use the Elasticsearch integration exclusively, Hibernate Search ignores the Lucene analyzers by default. The only way to force Hibernate Search to take the Lucene configuration into account is by putting an `@AnalyzerDef` annotation on one of your entities and not using it anywhere. You can also define it using programmatic mapping if adding annotations is not an option. It's odd, I know, but it's legacy behavior.

Another option would be for you to send a `highlight` query to Elasticsearch. However, this will require to access low-level APIs to send a JSON query, and I'm not even sure you can use the ES APIs to perform highlighting on an arbitrary piece of text (only on indexed documents). Some useful information if you want to investigate:

- You will have to [retrieve the Elasticsearch client](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/5.10/reference/en-US/html_single/#elasticsearch-client-access)
- [Here is the documentation for the REST client](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/5.6/java-rest-low.html) you will have to use
- The [highlighting API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.6/search-request-highlighting.html) in Elasticsearch 5.6 allows to highlight results when performing a Search query
- The [analyzer API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.6/indices-analyze.html) in Elasticsearch 5.6 allows to run analysis on an arbitrary string, but doesn't seem to provide highlighting.

Comment: Ok, I added a Lucene analysis definition provider (in addition to the existing ES analysis definition provider) and added the mapping for `hibernate.search.lucene.analysis_definition_provider` but it doesn't get called.  Any ideas?  Would it help to see all of the related hibernate.search property mappings being used?

Comment: Right, sorry about that. I updated my answer: if you use the Elasticsearch integration exclusively, Hibernate Search ignores the Lucene analyzers by default. The only way to force Hibernate Search to take the Lucene configuration into account is by putting an `@AnalyzerDef` annotation on one of your entities and not using it anywhere. It's odd, I know, but it's legacy behavior.

Comment: Excellent!  I added `@AnalyzerDef(name="dummyCustomAnalyzer", tokenizer = @TokenizerDef(factory = KeywordTokenizerFactory.class))` on 1 of our entities and just like you said, the newly added custom LuceneAnalysisDefinitionProvider was called at next startup. The existing highlighter code is now working as it used to.  I presume it's still best to convert all other queries to the new HibernateSearch Query DSL which is what I was in the process of doing when I ran into this highlighter code?

Comment: Glad it helped. Yes, using the query DSL is best if you want to use the Elasticsearch integration. The query DSL brings some schema validation when you build your queries, which is always nice to have. In the next major version of Hibernate Search, when Elasticsearch support will no longer be experimental, the DSL will be somewhat different, but it will be the only way to write queries for the Elasticsearch backend (apart from writing JSON directly). So moving to the query DSL at least brings you closer to what you'll need in 6.

Comment: Using low-level client approach with custom highlighting frame is something I've implemented in this lib https://github.com/json-ql/jsonql-hibernate-search-elastic, you can use it or check its sources to get a working example. It should be doable on Hibernate Search level but its implementation (ElasticsearchHSQueryImpl) is really badly written about subclassing and adding new features, so the low-level client approach seems to be the only one possible right now (at least with Hibernate 5.11.4.Final).

Comment: I updated my answer to mention a solution for Hibernate Search 6, which should require less hacking.

Comment: @yrodiere  I assume that the hibernate search 6 approach (probably the 5 version as well) will mean that we need to manually fetch the entity from the DB based on the ids from the json results & build the search results manually.  Is there some API/pattern to do this in-built in hibernate search

Comment: @bobby No, the Hibernate Search 6 approach doesn't mean you need to manually fetch the entity. You can perfectly well use multiple projections in the same query, e.g. `.select( f -> f.composite( f.jsonHit(), f.entity() ) )`. By default this return a `List`, but you can also use custom wrappers:  `.select( f -> f.composite( MyPair::new, f.jsonHit(), f.entity() ) )`. See https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#search-dsl-projection-composite . And no, there is no built-in support for highlighting yet; see https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HSEARCH-2192

Comment: @yrodier I'm now in the process of converting up to Hibernate Search 6 and Highlighting has come up again.  I understand the approach you give above using requestTransformer in theory (haven't tried in practice yet), however is it possible to Highlight (highlighter.getBestFragment) data that is NOT indexed, basically comparing 2 terms, as with the isMatch example above, using a built query?  If that's not possible with requestTransformer, is there another way to do it, even if we need to use Lucene directly like we ended up doing with HS 5?  Let me know if you'd prefer a new question on this.

Comment: @RickGagne Maybe create a separate question, it's hardly practical to do this in comments :)